# Retrieve word count from PDF with exclusion rules

Tags: python, regex, pdf, pdf-generation

I am in search of a module which can retrieve word count from a PDF document, with the possibility to add exclusion rules (such as appendix, content page, front page, and so forth).

I have found the following module : [PyPDF2](https://pythonhosted.org/PyPDF2/PdfFileReader.html). I could use it to create the functionality I want. Not sure how to handle exclusion rules properly though.

Here is a code snippet (from the following [eBook](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter13/)) for reading words from a specific page :

```
import PyPDF2
File = open('somefile.pdf', 'rb')
read = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(File)
page = pdfReader.getPage(0) # I.e front page
page.extractText() # contains a list of strings
```

For word count, obvious exceptions are `\n` and `\t`.

An option could be to instead do word count on the `.tex` file which generates the PDF (not always possible, unless you actually have the `.tex` file). Problem with this approach lies in knowing which keywords to ignore during count.

Finally, the easiest approach is to copy all the words in the PDF file, and paste them in an online word counter, like [wordcounter.net](https://wordcounter.net/).

Regardless, I hope I do not have to implement this and instead just use a module which does this already. That way I can run a script and append, e.g. `.tex` file, and add the count automatically. Which comes in handy.

**Edit:** I found a [good site](https://www.binpress.com/tutorial/manipulating-pdfs-with-python/167) which lists different modules for manipulating PDF's with Python. Still, nothing related to the functionality I have posted here.

Comment: One possible is to tokenise the input. Then count word frequencies, excluding the exceptions (such as \n and \t).